# Internal Server Error 500 on my server due to DistributionNotFound who_ldap>=3.2.2

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, turbogears2

I'm trying to run a Turbogears2 application on WSGI mod under Apache 2.4.25:

My virtualhost seems to be ok: /etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName www.site.com
        #ServerAdmin "Charlie ROOT"

        # ISTC is the only application on this server, thus will be served from /
        WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/site.egg/apache/app.wsgi

        # Have apache serving static content directly (not through WSGI)
        Alias /img /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/site.egg/ehp/public/img
        Alias /css /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/site.egg/ehp/public/css
        Alias /js /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/site.egg/ehp/public/js

        # Execution is "daemon mode"
        WSGIProcessGroup www.site.com
        WSGIDaemonProcess www.site.com user=www-data group=www-data threads=4 python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

My file /etc/apache2/apache.conf seems to cointain rigth policy too :

```
<Directory / >
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So this give me an Internal Server Error ...

I checked Apache var/log/error.log :

```
mod_wsgi (pid=15064): Target WSGI script '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/site.egg/apache/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module

mod_wsgi (pid=15064): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/site.egg/apache/app.wsgi'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
.
................
........................................
.......................................
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 849, in resolve
         raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
DistributionNotFound: The 'who_ldap>=3.2.2' distribution was not found and is required by site
```

I just reinstall "who_ldap-3.2.2.tar.gz" module successfully so i don't understand ... Is it a python path problem ? How to correct it ?

Comment: You should need ``python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages``. If you find it is needed, then mod_wsgi may be compiled for a different Python version than what you want to use.

Comment: Yes, I already specified my 'python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' in Apache virtualhost. Is there another file where I must to specify ?

Comment: Whoops, that should have read 'should not need'. Python should look in that location by default anyway. So if taking that out causes things to not work at all, then mod_wsgi is likely not compiled for the version of Python you are trying to use.

Comment: Ah ok, I removed python-path and there is no difference, however this is written in the documentation, part 7 (to let python-path): http://turbogears.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/deploy/mod_wsgi.html
What does that means that mod_wsgi is likely not compiled for the version of Python I'm trying to use ? How can I correct it ?

Comment: Work out what version of Python it is compiled for and which it is using. See  http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use and http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library

Comment: M python version is :
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
And I can't use ldd commande, I'm not using module ‘mod_wsgi.so’. I'm using a traditional Apache module installed into an existing Apache installation.

Comment: When using a traditional Apache module in an existing Apache installation, there will still be a mod_wsgi.so file. It will be in the Apache modules directory. The mod_wsgi module doesn't support static linking into Apache and no Linux distro uses static link of Apache modules.

Comment: Ok thank you very much ! I got this result after checked python shared lybrary, so it seems to be ok.
`/var/www/site# ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
 ...
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f19cc672000)
 ...
/var/www/site# unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/var/www/site# ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
        ...
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f0a27071000)`
How to execute Python installation in use now ? with the function 
`def application(environ, start_response):`

Comment: From the command line Python, if you do ``import who_ldap; print(who_ldap.__file__)``, what do you get?

Comment: I got this :
`>>> import who_ldap
>>> print(who_ldap.__file__)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/who_ldap-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/who_ldap/__init__.pyc
>>>`

Comment: All I can suggest is you compare ``sys.path`` in command line Python with what ``sys,path`` is in the WSGI application when running under mod_wsgi. Also make sure that permissions on installed packages under ``/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`` are such that they are readable by others and haven't somehow been installed with strange file system permissions.

Comment: My sys.path contains a lot of path, LDAP is :
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap3-1.4.0-py2.7.eg‌​g`
While the error in apache logs are : 
`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 640, in find_egg_entry_point
pkg_resources.require(self.spec)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py"‌​, line 963, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py"‌​, line 849, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
Distrib.. who_ldap not found`

Comment: Next thing to try would be to ``pip uninstall`` the ``who_ldap`` package. Do that multiple times until it says it can't be removed. There may be multiple versions sitting there which is confusing things. Then install the desired version again.